# how do i set radio button as checked based on database values in django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

here is my html code

```
<input type="radio" name="cast" id="open" style="margin-left:10px;text-align:left;" value="Open" {% if data.cast %}checked{% endif %} required>Open
                    <input type="radio" name="cast" id="sebc" style="margin-left:10px;text-align:left;" value="SEBC" {% if data.cast %}checked{% endif %} required>SEBC
                    <input type="radio" name="cast" id="sc/st" style="margin-left:10px;text-align:left;" value="SC/ST" {% if data.cast %}checked{% endif %} required>SC / ST
                    <input type="radio" name="cast" id="other" style="margin-left:10px;text-align:left;" value="Other" {% if data.cast %}checked{% endif %} required>Other
```

I did this but it didn't work for me.
the `data.cast` is variable having database value.

Comment: Have you looked into using Django's `forms` framework?

Comment: i am not using django's forms,i have manually created the form. can you please guide me for the right way? thank you

Comment: @marksjason, Django forms will be a great choice. It will reduce your code. You can read official docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/). However look at this tutorial [link](https://djangobook.com/mdj2-django-forms/) too.

Comment: my problem is solved. thankyou @k33da_lets_debug ,but i'm pretty sure django do not allow template designing as we need? any solution for that?

Comment: @marksjason Django allows customizing form templates (Some trade-offs are there). However it can be done while configuring the form. You can also use 3rd party packages to customize forms UI. See this package [Django-Crispy-Forms](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) I personally use this for form UI customization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it's late to answer it, I was having the same issue just now. You will have to compare it in terms of value but it's not a good practice especially when there's a lot of radio options to do it with.

```
<input type="radio" name="cast" id="open" style="margin-left:10px;text-align:left;" value="Open" {% if data.cast != 'SEBC' and data.cast != 'SC/ST' and data.cast != 'Other' %} checked {% endif %} required>Open
<input type="radio" name="cast" id="sebc" style="margin-left:10px;text-align:left;" value="SEBC" {% if data.cast != 'Open' and data.cast != 'SC/ST' and data.cast != 'Other' %} checked {% endif %} required>SEBC
<input type="radio" name="cast" id="sc/st" style="margin-left:10px;text-align:left;" value="SC/ST" {% if data.cast != 'SEBC' and data.cast != 'Open' and data.cast != 'Other' %} checked {% endif %} required>SC / ST
<input type="radio" name="cast" id="other" style="margin-left:10px;text-align:left;" value="Other" {% if data.cast != 'SEBC' and data.cast != 'SC/ST' and data.cast != 'Open' %} checked {% endif %} required>Other
```

Note: I have also tried it with just this:

```
{% if data.cast == 'yourvalue' %} checked {% endif %}
```

But, for some reason this doesn't work.

Comment: I am Thankful for your concern @Maisum Abbas. I got the thing worked long ago, and your answer here is exactly what I did. As you said It's not a good practice though but it did the trick.